# How to simulate magnetic field of a toroidal solenoid?

Tags: simulation, electromagnetism, solenoid, matlab, software

I am trying to simulate the magnetic flux inside and outside of a classic toroidal solenoid. The simulation must be able to simulate a toroidal solenoid with several densely wound layers of copper wire.

The issue is that I can create a toroidal coil from a parametric curve, but am limited to one layer of windings and am computationally limited in my number of turns (meshing alone takes hours). COMSOL allows you to create coils by defining a direction of current flow and specifying a number of turns. This would solve the meshing problem, but I have not been able to implement this for a toroidal coil. I am unsure of how to proceed.

Which simulation tool should I investigate for this task? In short, I have looked into ANSYS and COMSOL, but have trouble creating a simulation of the magnetic field through a toroidal solenoid with multiple layers of windings.

I would be extremely grateful for any pointers, as I have been puzzling over this for two weeks.

Comment: The usual way to solve toroidal magnetic problems is to assume radial symmetry in the solution. This reduces the problem from 3 dimensions to 2. However, I don't know exactly what you are trying to determine, so...

Comment: Beowulf, is this a in-depth physics kind of question or a practical engineering question? COMSOL let's you pretty much specify anything if you can write out all the needed PDEs. ANSYS, not so much from what I understand but it's lots easier for practical problems. Are you an experimental physicist working on some esoteric sensor? Or just making practical stuff where you can use higher level models and ignore the finer details?

Comment: Do should not use finite elements as there is no PDE to solve here. Just use Biot Savart to sum the contributions from current elements. One tool is a Matlab program called BSmag, which you can find at the Matlab file exchange. There is a similar Python tool but I have never tried it. You could also use Radia but it is more adapted to volume current elements than to filamentary elements.

Comment: @jonk I'm trying to find out what the toroid's external field looks like vs the number of windings. If an "ideal" toroid would have an external magnetic field of zero, I'm trying to find out how many windings are required to have an external magnetic field that approaches zero, with minimal leakage. I'm not experienced with PDEs, so was hoping there would be a user-friendly solution similar to ANSYS.

Comment: I’m not sure what is stopping you from doing the calculation. Just model the wire paths and sum up the fields due to each current segment. BSmag is a ready-to-go tool for this. No meshing is needed. When you are is an open domain and you have an exact Green’s function (that’s what Biot Savart is) just use it. It is many orders faster than trying to do 3D finite elements.

Comment: I will give that a try. Thank you for your advice, @10ppb

Comment: have you completed it? i'm also interested in that structure and magnetic field

Comment: @mjs Yes, I did. The solution (in COMSOL) was to: 1) define a parametric curve that models the toroidal coil. It will appear as a toroid with an infinitely thin wire. 

2) Then create a circle that has roughly the diameter of your wire and position it so that it is orthogonal to the start/end of the “wire” you created with the parametric curve operation. Select this circle and choose the sweep operation using your new parametric curve as the “path” of the sweep. Now you have an object to work with. In the physics section, you can add a current at the terminus of the object

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [www.emworks.com](http://www.emworks.com)

Activate a trial or an educational license.

Comment: Do you have any affliation with this product? If so, you should declare it.

Comment: I got no affiliation with that product. I used it in the past thanks to an evaluation license which was given to me because I attended a 2-day course.